# Most elegant way to reset a class

Tags: c++

For a class with subclasses or sctructures inside, what's the most ellegant way of reseting it?

```
class attributes {
public:
   std::string address;
   short       port;
   std::vector< std::string > data;
   struct Foo foo;
};
```

what's is the most elegant in a loop, default operator = ou create an Reset method memoring 0 the structure `memset(...)`?

```
   attributes obj, originalStateToResetObj;
   for(;;)
      //do stuff with obj
      obj.address = "172.0.0.1"
      //etc
      //reseting obj using operator=
      obj = originalStateToResetObj;
      // OR using Reset?
      obj.Reset();
   }
```

Other elegant suggestion?

Comment: The most elegant way is to create a new instance each time you need one.

Comment: @juanchopanza & that should be an answer.

Comment: But memory expensive... wouldn't?

Comment: Not always. That would depend on how many resources the object allocates.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP refers to s.th. like the [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel not necessarily memory expensive. It really depends on the situation. But one should determine these things empirically.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel At least memset won't be working properly with the `std::vector<std::string>` or any other non primitive attributes. Provide proper default and copy constructors, assignment operator and eventually move semantics. Then remember the object states you want to in their own instances and reassign them when necessary.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel If I'm not mistaken, what juanchopanza means is declaring `obj` inside the loop, letting it go out of scope at each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This completely depends on the class at hand.  Generally the right thing to do would be create a new one from scratch or use the class's copy constructor, but if it's using expensive resources, e.g. opening an IMAP connection (this example comes to mind since IMAP servers often limit the number of connections allowed per user quite strictly), then this can have very unwanted side-effects.

If a class has no zero-argument constructor then it makes little sense to "reset" it to some default state, so you will need to consider that as well.

Consider Memento design pattern if there is meaningful intermediate state you do need to retain.

Comment: Creating a new object for each interaction would be memory expensive, zeroing the actual would be process expensive =/

Comment: Zeroing the actual is way not safe - are you clobbering shared pointers?  Not freeing deeper memory?  Leaving the object in a totally invalid state?  This is C++, not assembly.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel why would it be memory expensive? You only have one instance per loop iteration.

Comment: memory expensive in the impotesis of creating a new instance instead reseting the actual @juanchopanza, for example if I create another instance and then pass it to a vector the same class will be in memory 3 times (original, the one that shoud be reseted, the other that stl does to std::vector).

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel - there's a vector which has deep data and instance data that needs to be consistent.  I haven't studied the implementation of vector but have dealt with outages caused by zeroing a C++ string.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel no, there would be two instances, possibly only one. You need to completely remove "the one that should be reseted". That is the whole point.